# Run jpegoptim in a cronjob once a week, on CentOS from within cPanel, only for files added within the past week?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos, cron

I've installed jpegoptim and can manually run it via the SSH command line:

```
jpegoptim *.jpg --strip-all
```

I'd like to take that command line and put it into a Cronjob that runs once a week. I'm running CentOS, and I'd like to set the Cronjob up in the cPanel.

However, I'm not sure of what syntax I should be using for the Cronjob to get it to run this command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example would be, via `crontab -e`

`@weekly cd /path/to/jpeg/files && jpegoptim *.jpg --strip-all`

If you want to more specifically specify when the job will run, look at the help in `man 5 crontab`.  For example, to run every sunday night at 3am:

`00 03 * * 0 cd /path/to/jpeg/files && jpegoptim *.jpg --strip-all`